# Must I capitalize Tivoli?

Tags: capitalization

In this sentence: "Bakken is the world's oldest tivoli", must tivoli be capitalized ? 
My program's atleast trying to make me think I must.

Comment: Would you write 'new york' (sorry, 'new amsterdam')?

Comment: Bakken is not the world’s oldest Tivoli—that honour belongs to the [Italian town](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tivoli,_Lazio), which has been around for almost 3,000 years. Bakken is rather the world’s oldest ***amusement park***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're Danish ... ? I'm confused, is "tivoli" commonly used as a word to mean "any" amusement park?

If so - yeah - leave it capital, if you're writing in English.

It would be like saying:

"< some theme park > is the world's oldest Disneyland."

or

"< some fast food chain > is the world's oldest McDonalds."

Here, you're using "Disneyland" to stand in for any theme park;

you're using "McDonalds" to stand in for any fast food chain.

Note that we often in English use "specific things" in a "general way" like that - it's a smartass sound that magazine writers like; it makes you look pseudointelligent.

So yeah in these examples, you're very much still talking about McDonalds or Disneyland, so they would be capitalised.

Same deal using "Tivoli" as a "generalised way to refer to that category of thing."

[image: Picture of the Tivoli Gardens]

I've noticed that my fellow european languages, have, very different/confusing takes on **when to use capital letters**.  (You need only look at, say, words for days of the week.)

So, **if you're writing in English**, yeah it would look totally weird if you have lower-case.  I can't think of any reason or situation you'd ever write "Tivoli" in lower-case. Exactly as with, say simply, a name - Smith - you'd simply never see Smith in lowercase. Hope it helps in some way!

Comment: I would upvote this answer if the editorializing  ("pseudointelligent") was removed. As it is, Joe, I'm tempted to downvote (but I'll abstain, for the moment).

Comment: Big Dan!  Dude - you've gotta take every possible opportunity to rip on advertising copywriters. If they're not available .. journalists!  :-O

Comment: On a serious note I feel bad I don't know the technical terms when you use a proper name, or single thing, in that way, as a general perhaps category is the best word.

Comment: The technical term is [metonymy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) and it enjoys a long and distinguished history (unless, of course, you consider Shakespeare a *pseudointellectual*).

Comment: Hmm, isn't metonymy more like (say) Hollywood to mean the film industry.  (Many examps on the wiki page, say "Australia votes!" and so on.)   Is this a type of metonymy?  ("Using one of a type to reference the entire category or kind")  Example in the southern US, "Coke" often means ALL soft-drinks (confusingly to outsiders!); traditionally in outback Australia "Toyota" was used for any brand 4x4. (I see this less often, other than with brands like Hoover.)

Comment: The examples you gave in your answer, of McDonalds and Disneyland, are classic metonymy. The Coke example is what's known as synecdoche, a hyponym (subtype) of metonymy. Check out the Wikipedia page I linked to, it's got all the details (and plenty of examples).

Comment: I appreciate that, being smashed, I forgot the word metonymy and you reminded me - you rock.  Well done. FWIW on the funny wikipedia page I see no examples of "Using one of a type to reference the entire category or kind".  It's not, really, a genericized trademark - but sort of like that. Anyways cheers for tonight!

Comment: @DanBron Excellent post on metonymy. Modern examples would include "Xerox" for any photocopy and "Hoover" for any vacuum cleaner. As for Shakespeare's usage of it, I'm sure there are tons of examples, but the only one that springs immediately to mind is Shylock's line from The Merchant of Venice: "A Daniel come to judgement, yea a Daniel!"

Comment: Your confusion in the first paragraph is entirely understandable, Joe. _Tivoli_ has indeed become somewhat of a genericised trademark in Danish, referring to any amusement park, at least to some. Personally, I still consider it a proper name belonging primarily to the town in Lazio and secondarily to the Tivoli Gardens in Copenhagen; I’d use _forlystelsespark_ (‘amusement park’) for Bakken, which is north of Copenhagen. The genericisation has no doubt been helped along by Tivoli Friheden in Aarhus (‘Freedom Tivoli’—proper Freedom Fries name!).